# How does std::apply forward parameters without explicit std::forward?

Tags: c++, c++17, perfect-forwarding, stdapply

Consider possible implementation of [`std::apply`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply):

```
namespace detail {
template <class F, class Tuple, std::size_t... I>
constexpr decltype(auto) apply_impl(F &&f, Tuple &&t, std::index_sequence<I...>) 
{
    return std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuple>(t))...);
}
}  // namespace detail

template <class F, class Tuple>
constexpr decltype(auto) apply(F &&f, Tuple &&t) 
{
    return detail::apply_impl(
        std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Tuple>(t),
        std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<std::decay_t<Tuple>>>{});
}
```

Why when invoking the function(`f`) with tuple of parameters to pass(`t`) we don't need to perform `std::forward` on each element of the tuple `std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuple>(t))...` in the implementation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not need to `std::forward` each element because `std::get` is  overloaded for rvalue-reference and lvalue-reference of tuple.

`std::forward<Tuple>(t)` will give you either a lvalue (`Tuple &`) or an rvalue (`Tuple &&`), and depending on what you get, `std::get` will give you a `T &` (lvalue) or a `T &&` (rvalue). See the various overload of [`std::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get).

---

A bit of details about [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) and [`std::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) -

As mentioned by [StoryTeller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41260745/2666289), every member of a tuple is an lvalue, whether it has been constructed from an rvalue or a lvalue is of no relevance here:

```
double a{0.0};
auto t1 = std::make_tuple(int(), a);
auto t2 = std::make_tuple(int(), double());
```

The question is - Is the tuple an rvalue? If yes, you can move its member, if no, you have to do a copy, but `std::get` already take care of that by returning member with corresponding category.

```
decltype(auto) a1 = std::get<0>(t1);
decltype(auto) a2 = std::get<0>(std::move(t1));

static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(a1), int&>{}, "");
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(a2), int&&>{}, "");
```

Back to a concrete example with [`std::forward`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward):

```
template <typename Tuple>
void f(Tuple &&tuple) { // tuple is a forwarding reference
    decltype(auto) a = std::get<0>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple));
}

f(std::make_tuple(int())); // Call f<std::tuple<int>>(std::tuple<int>&&);
std::tuple<int> t1;
f(t1); // Call f<std::tuple<int>&>(std::tuple<int>&);
```

In the first call of `f`, the type of `a` will be `int&&` because `tuple` will be forwarded as a `std::tuple<int>&&`, while in the second case its type will be `int&` because `tuple` will be forwarded as a `std::tuple<int>&`.

Comment: what if we pass to the `get` `std::tuple<int&&>&` and then after `get` we would perfect forward result element? would it work the same?

Comment: `you cannot create a std::tuple of reference`? so what is `std::forward_as_tuple` doing?

Comment: Of course you can create a tuple of references http://ideone.com/rm8rAZ

Comment: @Holt in my understanding when you create a field to store that rvalue reference it would loose its rvalue reference properties as it would have a name... and so you to achieve perfect forwarding you would need to `std::forward` it, again? But of course I might be missing something...

Comment: @W.F. reference collapsing kicks in, the value category of `tuple<int&&>&` is *lvalue*, hence you get `tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<int&&>>&` which is `int&& & -> int&`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki `tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<int&&>>` is `int&&` right? So if we `forward<tuple_element_t<0, decay_t<decltype(tup_ref)>>>(get<0>(tup_ref))` we would end up with forwarded rvalue reference on int, or not?

Comment: you end up with an rvalue expression referring to that `int` member

Comment: you never get a copy with `std::get`, what happens next depends on how the expression is used

Comment: @W.F. probably you should change your mindset a bit and think of `std::forward` as a conditional `std::move`, and of `std::move` as a plain cast, nothing more. the above answer is, at least for me, hard to parse, especially the *"You cannot forward something that is not a forwarding reference"* part

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki After your comments I understand that my answer is fuzzy, so I will try update it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 3):

`std::forward` is used to make sure that everything arrives at the call site with the correct value category.

But every member of a tuple is an lvalue, even if it's a tuple of `rvalue` references.

Comment: exactly that's my point we might want to pass rvalue references to the function `f`

Comment: even if the forward would be done inside the std::invoke the function wouldn't be able to know if the parameter is rvalue reference, no?

Comment: @W.F. - We would be able to know. But like Holt elaborated, the only time we can assume that the temporary bound to the rvalue reference in the tuple is still a valid object, is if the tuple itself is bound to an rvalue reference. So it is the value category of the tuple itself that should win out always.

Comment: @W.F. - In case my previous example wasn't to well written, an illustration: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9bcc65c3929968cf

Comment: Yup when using references we need to be careful... but it might be really time-saving...

Comment: @W.F. - I think the standard, as always, leaves such considerations in the hands of the developer. It handles the safe case by itself, and if you are careful and know what you're doing, you can just `std::move` the tuple :)